# How can I Import my own package in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I created my own repository using `flutter create --template=package test_repository`. The repository is inside a folder called `packages` inside my root directory

My hierarchy looks like this:

```
-lib
  -test.dart
-packages
  -test_repository
    -lib
    -pubspec.yaml
-pubspec.yaml
```

I imported my test_repository inside the main pubspec.yaml using:

```yaml
dependencies:
  test_repository:
    path: packages/test_repository
```

I'm trying to import my repository inside `test.dart` using:

```dart
import 'package:test_repository/test_repository.dart';
```

The error I receive:

> Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:test_repository/test_repository.dart'.
> Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or try using a URI for a file that does exist.darturi_does_not_exist